OpenTelemetry .NET: Metrics getting duplicated with UpDownCounters and ObservableGauges
I have just started using OpenTelemetry with .NET. I have a use case where I need to log custom metrices, such as success and failure counts in the application. To avoid data duplication, I am using Delta temporality preference. While this have been successful with regular counters, I’m still encountering duplicate data issues with "UpDownCounters" and "ObservableGauges". Can anyone explain how to resolve this?
Below sample code for the same,
using var meterProvider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .AddMeter("MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary")
    .AddConsoleExporter((options, readerOptions) =>
    {
        readerOptions.TemporalityPreference = MetricReaderTemporalityPreference.Delta;
    })
    .Build();

var abc = new Main();
abc.Execute();

internal class Main
{
    private readonly Meter _meter = new("MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary");

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");

        _meter.CreateCounter<long>("MyFruitCounter_v1")
            .Add(3, new("name", "apple"), new("color", "red"), new("uid", "9161"));

        _meter.CreateUpDownCounter<long>("MyFruitGauge_v1")
            .Add(3, new("name", "apple"), new("color", "red"), new("uid", "9161"));

        Console.WriteLine("Logged values!");

        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

OpenTelemetry
The data for LongSumMonotonic type should also come only once just like LongSum. I tried the same with ObservableGauge as well and still the same result.
